# Divisibility of a general polynomial of a rational expression

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, polynomial-rings, multivariate-polynomial

> Let   $P_0(y),P_1(y),...,P_n(y)\in\mathbb{C}[y]$ where $P_n(y)\neq 0$, and let $p(x),q(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ coprime, both nonzero and $q(x)$ nonconstant. Consider the multivariate polynomial
> $$P(x,y)=P_0(y)p(x)^0q(x)^n+P_1(y)p(x)^1q(x)^{n-1}+...+P_n(y)p(x)^nq(x)^0.$$
> Can $q(x)$be a divisor of $P(x,y)$?

I already found that $q(x)$ cannot be a divisor of $p(x)$, $q(x)^0$ and $P_0(y),...,P_n(y)$.

The question comes from deciding under which conditions an equation
$$\sum_{i=0}^nP_i(y)\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)^i=0$$
is irreducible if the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^nP_i(y)x^i$ is irreducible. I want to be sure and need confirmation therefore.

Comment: Of course $q(x)$ isn't constant if $\gcd(p,q)=1$

Comment: You don't have to see $q\nmid p$. It has already been said: $q$ and $p$ are coprime.

Comment: Also, $\{p,q\}\ne 0$. The null-polynomial isn't a constant because, if you ask for it, $\deg (0)=-1\;\lor\;\deg(0)=-\infty$ . Let $c$ be a constant. $\deg(c)=0$

Comment: So, if $P(x,y)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n P_i(y)p(x)^iq^{n-i}$, $q(x)$ should (if it were a divisor of $P(x,y)\;$), divide $P_n(y)p(x)^n$. $\gcd(p,q)=1\implies q\mid P_n$, but they don't have any common roots (even if $P_i(y)$ isn't a constant) since $q(x)\in\mathbb C[x]$ and $P_i(y)\in\mathbb C[y]$

Comment: And, that is exactly what you've stated. So, what went wrong? (:

Comment: Until you edit the post, don't just see if it can be reopened with no improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $q(x)$ divides $P_k(y)p(x)^kq(x)^{n-k}$ for all $k<n$. So the question is whether $q(x)$ can divide $P_n(y)p(x)^n$. Given that $\gcd(p(x),q(x))=1$, the question is whether $q(x)$ can divide $P_n(y)$. Given that $P_n(y)\neq0$ and $q(x)$ is not constant, the answer is no.